# kdb+/q parse a string representing a table name to an actual table

Tags: kdb

Can currently get the count of a partitioned table by doing `.Q.cn tableName`.

Now want to wrap this up as a function to make a remote call. How can one parse a string  to be a partitioned table? Here is what I am trying to do:

```
myFunc{[x]
  flip `date`env!(.Q.PV;Q.cn x)
};
/ the below line will give a rank error
myFunc["tableName"]

/ the below line will not, assuming tableName is an existing table in the current namespace
myFunc[tableName]
```

I have tried using `parse`, `eval`, and similar methods to try and parse the string to be interpreted as the table on the remote host without any success so far. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `select count i by date from tableName` is a special case query which will automatically run `.Q.cn` under the hood

```
myFunc{[x]
  0!select env:count i by date from x
};
```

Pass a symbol to run:

```
q)myFunc[`tableName]
date       env
--------------
2020.01.01 3
2020.01.02 3
```

If you want to pass a string just add `` `$ `` to cast it in the function.

You could also use `get` or `value`:

```
myFunc{[x]
  flip `date`env!(.Q.PV;Q.cn value x)
};
```

Or `eval`

```
myFunc{[x]
  flip `date`env!(.Q.PV;Q.cn eval `$x)
};
```